# I am using a 2 column template in Expression Web 4 - How do I keep sidebar equal sizes?

Tags: html, css

I attempted the solution that another person listed, and it kind of equaled it out, but because the content section grows depending on what I put in it, it looks goofy with the side bar staying the smaller size.

I am open to ideas, but I would rather have the column move with the content, such as floating up and down, or... At least show the same size...

The following is what I have in CSS now:

```
@import url("layout.css");
 body {
    font-family:"Georgia", "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: #764;
    background-image: url("../images/background.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
#container {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
#masthead {
    text-align: center;
    width: 698px;
    border: 1px solid #431;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image:;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 148px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #431;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    width: 518px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #431;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#footer {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    width: 698px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #431;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

The webpage can be seen at http://www.crucifiedwithchrist.org.

Thanks,
John

Comment: easy to follow tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

Comment: I used this! Thank you. it does keep the side bar in place, and works! Now, the only catch is to get rid of the bottom bar, which is easy enough and if the side bar remains in place, then, it is not needed... Now, question: How do I keep the top in place, if I go this way?

Answer (score 0):

define `height`

```
#navigation {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 148px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: 1px solid #431;
background-color: #fff;
height: 730px;
}
```

Comment: Is that going to set a specific height? I am pretty new to Expression, as I use to use FrontPage, but, as I have learned, that is obsolete now... Unfortunately, this is a ministry website (a new one) and I don't have a lot of cash at this point to pay someone to write the site at this point, though hopefully here in the future?

Comment: Ok, so defined height to 730px, and it works on the homepage, but it still is small on others.. Is there a better option to make it grow proportionally with the content?

Comment: Yes. the box has to be within the main body and thus would have the same size. 
this is very easy, not cost much.